# Memcache that is not TCP-based?

Tags: php, caching

I recently implemented `memcache` and `memcached` to my PHP implementation. None of them are fast enough, since they are based on TCP. It would be nice if there was a solution that stored my data across sessions, directly in the memory.

Is that possible? I haven't been able to find a solution that allows me to do so.

**Edit**

"Not fast enough" as in I am trying to store about 130 rows, about 100 times. Each rowset has different data defined by a key. I am defining them fast. The limitation might be the serialization, since the data itself is not that large byte-wise.

I am hoping for an in-memory solution that supports storing the object's bytes directly in the memory to get rid of the need for serialization.

I already tried the `IG_BINARY` serialization mode for `memcached`.

Comment: define "not fast enough".

Comment: I believe that memcache supports unix socket connections, that would be quicker.

Comment: Consider redis as an alternative

Comment: I redefined the question.

Comment: I really disagree with this question being closed, for the named reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use APC, the Alternative PHP Cache. Only works on the same host, as it indeed doesn't use network traffic.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php